# Manifold, velocity vector, trajectory

Tags: vectors, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

[Here](http://www.math.toronto.edu/karshon/grad/2010-11/flows.pdf) on page 1,
in the 4th paragraph, how do I choose $s$ so that $\gamma_2(t)=\gamma_1(s+t)$
for all $t \in R$? Does this mean that both, direction and size of the velocity vectors at $p$ are the *same*? Is there any intuition and/or proof behind this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $\gamma_1(t) = \psi_t(m_1), \gamma_2(t) = \psi_t(m_2)$. Let's assume

$$\gamma_1(t_1) = \psi_{t_1}(m_1) = \gamma_2(t_2) = \psi_{t_2}(m_2) = p$$

and set $s = t_1 - t_2$. Then

$$ \gamma_1(s + t) = \psi_{s + t}(m_1) = \psi_{t - t_2 + t_1}(m_1) = (\psi_{t} \circ \psi_{-t_2} \circ \psi_{t_1})(m_1) = (\psi_{t} \circ \psi_{ -t_2})(p) = \psi_t(m_2) = \gamma_2(t). $$

Comment: But, there is no $X$ mentioned in that paragraph,i.e. in the definition of trajectories. $X$ only becomes available in the 5th paragraph below. Cannot $X$ be different for different curves $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$,after all?

Comment: @user122424: Sorry, I didn't notice that. It's even easier if your definition of "integral curve" is the trajectory of a global flow. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Can you please see also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2318471/manifolds-vector-covector-evaluation-diffrenetial-pullback) question?