# manifolds, vector,covector,evaluation, diffrenetial, pullback

Tags: vectors, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

Suppose we have derived

$\phi^*(\beta)=\sum_{jR}b_R(\partial y^R/\partial x^j)dx^j$

as [here](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22in+terms+of+matrices%2C+the+differential%22) in (2.24). How do I obtain the formula (2.23) from (2.24). I.e. I want substitute $v$ into (2.24) and get $\phi^*(\beta)(v)$; what should be this last expression in coordinates?

If you cannot follow the link, just type

"in terms of matrices, the differential"

into
books.google.com

And follow the unique link there.

Answer (score 0):

Write $v$ as
$$\textstyle
v = \sum_j v^j \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}
$$
and multiply it from the left by
$$\textstyle
\phi^*(\beta)=\sum_{jR} b_R \frac{\partial y^R}{\partial x^j}dx^j.
$$
You will see that this is the same as the product of $\phi_*$ with $v$, that is
$$\textstyle
\sum_R \left(\sum_j \frac{\partial y^R}{\partial x^j} v^j \right) \frac{\partial}{\partial y^R},
$$
multiplied by
$$\textstyle
\beta = \sum_R b_R dy^R
$$
from the left.

In terms of matrices, this is indeed the matrix multiplication
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
b^1 & \dots & b^r\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial y^1}{\partial x^1} & \dots & \frac{\partial y^1}{\partial x^n} \\
\vdots & & \vdots \\
\frac{\partial y^r}{\partial x^1} & \dots & \frac{\partial y^r}{\partial x^n}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
v^1 \\
\vdots \\
v^n
\end{pmatrix}
$$
so $\phi^*(\beta)$ is just the product of the row vector on the left with the Jacobian matrix of $\phi_*$, everything relative to the given coordinates, of course.